# Is their a paper that gives a systematic analysis of performance measures for regression tasks?

Tags: regression, references

I have read a paper on [systematic analysis of performance measures for classification tasks](http://atour.iro.umontreal.ca/rali/sites/default/files/publis/SokolovaLapalme-JIPM09.pdf) and really liked it. Since then I have been searching for a similar paper on regression analysis.

Could you guys help me by providing a few references?

Comment: I am still interested in this question.

Comment: Any guidance is welcome.